# .htaccess mod_rewrite subdirectory to URL parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hope this was not asked over and over again before, but I didn't get further to an answer using google, w3schools and so on. So here is my question:
I'm writing a script that creates kind of an index of projects that I have on my homepage and makes a nice list with images and teaser text based on an info file. I mostly have my projects on github and the readme is in markdown so I thought I could dynamically generate the HTML from the markdown of the latest blob from github on demand using PHP so it gets updated automatically.
My directory structure looks like this:

```
projects
    project1
        .remoteindex
        .info
    project2
        .remoteindex
        .info
    index.php
    .htaccess
```

So when just `domain.tld/projects/` is requested I get the info from `.info` and make a nice index of all projects. But if `domain.tld/projects/project1/` is request it, I want to internally redirect it to `domain.tld/projects/?dir=project1` to do my markdown parsing and so on. But `domain.tld/projects/project1/image.png` should not be redirected.

This is what I tried:

```
.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?dir=$1 [R,L]
```

I made it redirect instead of rewrite so that I can see what the error is because I just got an 404. The URL that I get redirected to is `domain.tld/home/www/web310/html/projects/index.php?dir=project1` so obviously there is something going wrong with the internal structure of the web server an paths an whatever.
I hope you can understand my problem an I would be very pleased if someone could help me, because I'm totally lost on `.htaccess` anyway.

#### Edit:

See my answer below for the used `.htaccess`.

The strange thing is that if I have an `index.html` in on of the subdirectories, my local web server (Apache with XAMPP for Mac OS X 1.7.3) does not rewrite and the `index.html` gets displayed, without one it works correctly.But on my real web server that serves my homepage it rewrites both with and without `index.html` (which is what I want). Any hints on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the help so far! You guys are just awesome!

I figured out that a symbiosis of both of your solutions works well for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /projects
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?dir=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Of course only without `[R]`, this was my fault. (See my question edit for another question please).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `RewriteBase /projects` to the htaccess.
That way the redirect will work properly.

**Edit:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?dir=$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this gets me to a point where Firefox tells me:

    **The page isn't redirecting properly**
    Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: edited with my two hints, could you please add the rewrite logs in your question?

Comment: the problem was that index.php also matches `[^/]+`, so the url keeps on getting rewritten. I added some code in my post to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Following what you ask, this is important **not** to do a redirect, but let the rewriterule modify *internally* the URL i.e. the `RewriteRule` should **not** end with `[R,L]` but rather `[L]` and maybe the "`query string append`" directive to keep what's after the `?` so this should probably be `[QSA,L]`.

Now here's how I'd do to avoid rewriting static files: if it's not a file then (and only then) test it:

```
# if it's not a file...
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
# ... and it's a dir
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
# ... then rewrite it internally and stop further processing:
RewriteRule projects/([^/]+)(/?)$ index.php?dir=$1 [QSA,L]
```

### And now two hints:

Please try to use the [`RewriteLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: And unfortunately your answer isn't working either and it just gives me no redirect/rewrite at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I get an 500 if I turn `RewriteLog` on. W/o it there is no problem. I even tried to change the location of the logfile into my /html dir and it din't work.

Comment: You're in trouble man :)  500 when trying to use rewritelog means it's not your own webserver, and you're trying to do this in an htaccess file... this implies it's quite harder to debug.

Comment: I've modified it a bit (= optional trailing "/")